# Tensorflow: efficient way to pass inputs to an iterative program

Tags: tensorflow

Here is how my code looks like:

```
N = 16, num_ckfs = 5
init_variances = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, shape=[ num_ckfs, N],name='inital_variances')

init_states = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, shape=[num_ckfs, N], name='init_states')

#some more code

predicted_state =  prior_state_expanded + kalman_gain * diff_expanded

error_covariance = sum_cov_cholesky + tf.batch_matmul(kg , kalman_gain, adj_x=True)


projected_output = tf.batch_matmul(predicted_state,input_vectors_extra, adj_y=True)

session = tf.Session()  


init_var = [10 for i in range(N)]
init_var_ckfs = [init_var for i in range(num_ckfs)]



init_state = [0 for i in range(N)]
init_state_ckfs = [init_state for i in range(num_ckfs)]

for timestep in range(10):

   out= session.run([projected_output, predicted_state, error_covariance], {init_variances:init_var_ckfs, init_states:init_state_ckfs })

   #for the next tilmestep, I want to initialize init_state_ckfs with the predicted_state, and the init_var_ckfs with error_covariance.
   #predicted_state is a tensor with shape (num_ckfs, 1, N)
   #error_covariance is a tensor with shape (num_ckfs, N, N): I just need the diagonal elements from each of the N X N matrices
```

**Although I have mentioned this in the code as a comment, I will mention it here again. I am wanting to know how to use the updated tensors from the previous time step by converting them into lists and feeding them as inputs for the next time step.** Can someone please help me.

Answer (score 1):

use `tf.assign` to assign to the placeholder the last value of the variable. As long as the Session is active the state is preserved

Comment: could you please provide a simple example